# Copulas, implication

Tags: probability, special-functions

Let $C$ be a copula function. Prove that $C(t,1-t)=0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ implies that $C(u,v)=\max(u+v-1,0)$.

I think the implication other way around is easy to see, however I can't see why the "upper diagonal" part of the copula function could not be some type of a different function with $C(u,1)=u$ and $C(1,v)=v$.

See the image below - the leftmost plot is the Frechet-Hoeffding lower bound. I need to prove that $C$ is equal to that.

[image]

Comment: Where you wrote $C(t,1-t)=0$, did you mean that that should hold for EVERY value of $t$ between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I see you're reluctant to believe my answer, which may be counterintuitive at first. So let's try another way of looking at it. Suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Find the joint c.d.f. of $(X,1−X)$. You'll find it's precisely the leftmost plot currently appearing in your question, namely $(x,y)\mapsto\max\{x+y−1,0\}$. Surprising, perhpas, but true.

Answer (score 1):

the condition on C implies $U \ge 1-V$.  Since $U$ and $1-V$ are both uniform equality must hold, and $U = 1-V$.   See also frechet-hoeffding lower bound.

Comment: I fail to see how this proves the implication. $u=1-v$ at the secondary diagonal, that is clear from the outset. You simply restated the starting condition of the proof. Also, Frechet-Hoeffding lower bound is $\max(u+v-1,0)$, so we need to show that given the condition, $C$ is actually equal to this lower bound.
If I am wrong, please help me understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You're saying the probability of being below the diagonal $u+v=1$ is zero.

Now consider a point $(u,v)$ exactly on the diagonal, so that $u+v=1$.  What probability is assigned to the closed triangle with vertices $(u,v)$, $(1,v)$, and $(1,0)$?  By the definition of copula conjoined with the fact that the probability below the diagonal is $0$, it must be $1-u$.  And the probability assigned to that triangle must also be equal to the length of its projection onto the $v$-axis, and that length is also $1-u$.  But the probability of falling within that part of the $u$-axis is equal to the probability assigned to the closed trapezoid with vertices $(u,v)=(u,1-u)$, $(1,0$), $(u,1)$, and $(1,1)$.  That means the probability assigned to the rectangle with vertices $(u,v)=(u,1-u)$, $(1,v)$, $(u,1)$ and $(1,1)$ must be *zero*!  This holds for every value of $u$, thus for all such rectangles.

Conclusion: The probability of being *above* the diagonal must be $0$.

That means all the probability is concentrated on the diagonal $u+v=1$.  And there's only one distribution on the diagonal that gives the right marginal distributions to satisfy the definition of a copula.

The way I thought of this was by thinking first of the discrete case, the set of pairs $(u,v)$ of integers in the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  Just do the $2\times2$ and $3\times3$ cases and you see quickly why all the probability must be concentrated on that one diagonal, and must be uniformly distributed there.

Comment: The starting condition is $C(t,1-t)=0$, which means that the secondary diagonal gets zero weight. Moreover, the Frechet-Hoeffding lower bound, which we must show $C$ equals, states that all the mass is above the diagonal.

Comment: The condition $C(t,1-t)=0$ means the one point $(t,1-t)$ on the diagonal, plus all points below and/or to its left, gets weight $0$.  It does NOT mean that that diagonal gets weight $0$.

Comment: for all $t\in [0,1]$, I believe $(t,1-t)$ goes through all points on the diagonal. Keep in mind that we are talking about the diagonal that connects the points $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. If you look at a 3D-plot of the Frechet-Hoeffding lower bound copula, its diagonal has zero mass.

Comment: I understand that that point runs all the way through that diagonal.  That implies (among other things) that every individual point on that diagonal gets probability $0$.  But the fact that every individual point in that set gets probability $0$ does not mean that the set as a whole gets probability $0$.

Comment: I think you may be looking at the graph and thinking that since the c.d.f. equals $0$ at every point on that diagonal, the diagonal therefore gets probability $0$.  But that is an error.  Consider a rectangle with vertices $(u_1,v_1),(u_2,v_1),(u_1,v_2),(u_2,v_2)$, with $u_1<v_1$ and $u_2<v_2$ and all for points above that diagonal.  The probability of falling in that rectangle is $F(u_2,v_2)-F(u_1,v_2)-F(u_2,v_1)+F(u_1,v_1)$.  And we know $F(u,v)=u+v-1$ above the diagonal.  Go ahead and compute that probability.  You'll get $0$.  So the probability of being above the diagonal is $0$.

Comment: And likewise the probability of being below the diagonal is $0$.  Read the argument in my answer CAREFULLY.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: I didn't vote down.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rigorous proof:

Suppose $u + v - 1 \leq 0$. Then $v \leq 1-u$, so we must have
$$
0 = C(u,v) \leq C(u,1-u) = 0
$$

Now suppose $u + v - 1 > 0$.
Construct the rectangle $A = [u,1] \times [v,1]$.
Pick $z \in [1-v,u]$ and also construct the rectangle $B = [z, 1] \times [1-z, 1]$.
The volume of $B$ is given by
\begin{align*}
V_C(B) &= C(1,1) - C(z,1) - C(1,1-z) + C(z,1-z) \\
&= 1 - z - (1-z) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
Since $A \subseteq B$, this implies $V_C(A) = 0$.
We therefore have
\begin{align*}
0 &= V_C(A)\\
& = C(1,1) - C(u,1) - C(1,v) + C(u,v) \\
&=  1 - u - v +  C(u,v) \\
\Rightarrow \qquad  C(u,v) &= u + v - 1
\end{align*}
Combining these results, we can conclude that
$$
C(u,v) = \max(0,u + v -1)
$$