# Systematic elementary exposition of multivariate c.d.f.s?

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions

An example of some initially counterintuitive things that can happen with the joint cumulative probability distribution function of a tuple of real-valued random variables is found in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570023/copulas-implication).  The function on the left below is $C(x,y)=\max\{0,x+y-1\}$ for $x,y\in(0,1)$.  Last I checked, the poster was not yet convinced that this c.d.f. does not assign probability $0$ to the diagonal $\{(x,1-x) : 0<x<1\}$, and in fact, assigns probability $1$ to that set.  If we call the two random variables $X$ and $Y$, then we have $\Pr(X\le x\ \&\ Y\le y)=\max\{0,x+y-1\}$ for $x,y\in(0,1)$.  This might lead one to expect that $F_{X+Y}(w)=0$ for $w\le1$ and is a positively sloped straight line after that.  In fact it leaps upward at $1$ and is horizontal elsewhere, so $\Pr(X+Y=1)=1$.

**So my question is** whether there is a systematic elementary exposition of how to understand multivariate c.d.f.s that goes through all of the usual naive misunderstandings and instructs beginners in how to understand such things?

[image]

Comment: So you are saying the accordingly the CDF above the set $S=(0.9,1]\times(0.9,1]$, which lies above the diagonal has zero measure? $S=[X\le 1 \,\&\, Y\le 1] \backslash [X\le 0.9 \,\&\, Y\le 0.9]$ so $\Pr(S)=1-(0.9+0.9-1)=0.2$

Comment: Yes: The set of all points above the diaognal has measure zero.

Comment: @SergioParreiras : Perhaps you are misled by the fact that if this were a _density_ function rather than a c.d.f., then the fact that the function is positive in a certain region would mean that the measure of that region is positive. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Did and Michael: sorry for my confusion, you are right.

Comment: Math is all about finding interesting and non-obvious ways to write 0.  So, your question is like asking "is there a systematic elementary exposition of how to understand when an expression is 0?"   In your example, the joint CDF function is an unnatural description of the system, it seems constructed only to confuse. A more natural way is to define X uniform over (0,1) and define Y=1-X, then compute its joint CDF to show it is the given thing.  So, some ways of looking at things are just more natural and obvious than others, even though they are the same.

Comment: I just looked at the original question you linked to, and see that your comment there is essentially the same as my Y=1-X example! haha.  I also notice now that this question is really old.

Comment: Okay I just read thru your proof on the other question, I gave +1 there so that leaves your total votes there equal to (drum roll).....0.   Yet another fancy way to get 0. =)